# Unable to create blank page without head - Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have created the new layout called new layout inside my page layout folder and copied the contents of empty layout. The head content coming from the root template which i am unable to overwrite.

In mangento, I have done same using the new layout file, i have removed getChildHtml('head') ?>
This allows me to remove the head section.

Since magento can able to create any web app. i need to create a bank page using new layout.